# JSF and f:ajax for hiding/showing div

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, webforms, jakarta-ee

I am thinking of making a hidable/showable menu on my web application. Before this, I used PHP and AJAX extensively for this purpose. However, since HTML element id is regenerated in JSF framework I found out that this method is no longer feasible at least in my scope.

I have read f:ajax tag in JSF and tried to implement it. Apparently no luck for me. It looks so easy but I still could not find out what I did wrong.

I have prepared a prototype to test the f-ajax tag functionality but no luck. Here is the code

```
   ` <h:body>
     <h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText value="Click A" />
        <f:ajax event="click" render="textA"/>
    </h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText value="Click B" />
        <f:ajax event="click" render="textB"/>
    </h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText value="Click C" />
        <f:ajax event="click" render="textC"/>
    </h:outputLabel>

    <h:outputText id="textA" value="Click A" />
    <h:outputText id="textB" value="Click B" />
    <h:outputText id="textC" value="Click C" />
    </h:body>`
```

When I clicked the particular label, nothing happend. The textA, textB and textC elements are already rendered in the first place. What did I do wrong guys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, since HTML element id is regenerated in JSF framework

If that is so important, just specify fixed `id`s yourself. Each component has an `id` attribute for that. This way you should be able to use normal JS/jQuery frameworks whenever applicable.

As to the problem in the concrete question, here's a working example which should get you started.

```html
<h:form>
    <f:ajax render="text">
        <h:commandLink value="Click A" action="#{bean.setShow('A')}" /><br/>
        <h:commandLink value="Click B" action="#{bean.setShow('B')}" /><br/>
        <h:commandLink value="Click C" action="#{bean.setShow('C')}" /><br/>
    </f:ajax>

    <h:panelGroup id="text">
        <h:outputText value="Clicked A" rendered="#{bean.show == 'A'}" />
        <h:outputText value="Clicked B" rendered="#{bean.show == 'B'}" />
        <h:outputText value="Clicked C" rendered="#{bean.show == 'C'}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

in combination with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private String show;

    public String getShow() {
        return show;
    }

    public void setShow(String show) {
        this.show = show;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

reading your code I would first give some general suggestions:

- As far as I know ajax works on input elements but not on `outputLabel`. Use h:commandLink or h:commandButton instead
- `outputText` should not be inside `outputLabel`. outputLabel is not necessary here
- the `outputText` elements at the bottom are always shown unless you use the rendered attribute: `<h:outputText id="textA" value="Click" rendered="false" />`. You can use some EL-expression to make the rendered-attribute conditional.

I think the best would be to start with the [Java-EE-Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) to learn about the basic concepts of jsf.