# After showing / hiding a JSF element with AJAX how to hide the triggering element?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, rendering

I followed the intructions given by BalusC in [this answer][1]

[1]: [JSF and f:ajax for hiding/showing div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940551/jsf-and-fajax-for-hiding-showing-div) and it worked. But I want to hide the element when the command button is pressed and the element with the id="incorrectQuestion" is shown. I did it almost like in the example. I have tried a lot of combinations but I couldn't hide the command button.

```
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not answerResultBean.showIncorrectQuestions}">
                <div id="loginDiv" style="width: 400px; text-align: left;">
                    <center>
                        <f:ajax render="incorrectQuestions">
                            <br />
                            <h:commandButton value="#{strings.failedQuestions}"
                                action="#{answerResultBean.setShowIncorrectQuestions(true)}" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </f:ajax>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="incorrectQuestions">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{answerResultBean.showIncorrectQuestions}">
                    <div id="loginDiv" style="width: 400px; text-align: left;">
            ...
```

Comment: This construct will fail if the bean is request scoped and the `showIncorrectQuestions` property is not preserved during its (post)construction. Is your bean indeed request scoped?

Comment: No, the bean is session scoped. I just want after showing the second panel group to hide the first one.

Comment: Then please post an SSCCE. The problem is not visible in the code posted so far. On an unrelated note, the HTML `<center>` element is deprecated since HTML 4.01 in 1998. I suggest to polish your HTML and doublecheck if you're really learning HTML based on up to date resources and not ones which are over 15 years old.

Comment: I know that center is deprecated, but it still works and I put it there just for testing, it didn't worth the time to write into a CSS or something, if the code doesn't stay this way. In the final code I will use up to date methods. Well in the question that you answered, that I refer to, how do you hide the <f:ajax render="text"> <h:commandLink value="Click A" action="#{bean.setShow('A')}" /><br/> ...

Comment: Oh, this way. Just put the `<h:panelGroup>` containing the button inside `<h:panelGroup id="incorrectQuestions">` as well. Is this what you're concretely asking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `<h:panelGroup>` containing the button inside `<h:panelGroup id="incorrectQuestions">` as well. This way it will also be updated on ajax request and the `rendered` condition would cause it to be hidden.

By the way, try to keep your code DRY. You've there quite some code duplication.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="loginDiv" style="width: 400px; text-align: left;">
    <h:commandButton value="#{strings.failedQuestions}"
        action="#{answerResultBean.setShowIncorrectQuestions(true)}"
        style="text-align: center; margin: 10px;"
        rendered="#{not answerResultBean.showIncorrectQuestions}">
        <f:ajax render="loginDiv">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{answerResultBean.showIncorrectQuestions}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that a `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` generates a `<div>`. This way there's no need for a `<h:panelGroup><div>`.