# How to connect a commandButton with CheckBox

Tags: jsf

In a html page I have a `h:commandButton` that I want to make it to work in combination with a `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`, so every time I press the button the checkbox will be checked and otherwise.

Is it possible to do that directly in the html, and not in the java code behind it?

```
<h:commandButton  value="#{userBean.buttonText()}" action="#{userBean.changeOutput()}"/>        
<h:panelGrid columns="4" rendered="#{userBean.details}" styleClass="clicked" >
    <h:outputText .... />
    <h:outputText ..../>
</h:panelGrid>`
```

Comment: I wanted to make the connection here, not in the code behind it. The same way that I show and hide the panelGrid with the rendered attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 2, you have to update the area that include your checkbox, using [f:ajax](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/) tag.

You can find a lot of examples here in stackoverflow, look this example just hide/show a div: [After showing / hiding a JSF element with AJAX how to hide the triggering element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468882/after-showing-hiding-a-jsf-element-with-ajax-how-to-hide-the-triggering-elemen)

Hope it helps.